# gmail replay using smtp client thread not created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, gmail

I'm trying to send replay email using smtp client ,replay sent successfully but thread not created for mail , i need below replay see this link [https://ibb.co/drSCMp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmXPe.png)

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

client.Port = 587;
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Timeout = 10000;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new 
System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");

MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("username", "recieverusername, "Re:subject", "Replay From c#");
mm.Headers.Add("In-Reply-To", "<messageid>");
mm.Headers.Add("References", "<messageid>");
mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

client.Send(mm);
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "but thread not created for mail"? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @EduardMalakhov i am edited my post and added reference image which i need

Comment: I didn't understand the relation between Thread and the image you have uploaded. what do you mean by thread?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani when i send reply using above code i need thread in my mail like i attached screenshot but i'm not getting that thread